# How i can optimize the load of my page when i have severals Jquery Selectors at the start of my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have several jquery selector at the beginning of my javascript.

```
jQuery('.enter').show();
jQuery('.btnsecond').show();
jQuery('#id div.my-class').hide();
jQuery('.classes p:last').hide();
```

this jquery code run at any reload of the page...

I think its cause a process to select the correct DOM, which solution could be to simplify, or optimize this process of loading ? Maybe locate the dom diferently, using Css.

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing you can do to "optimize" this is to use `jQuery('.classes p').last().hide();` instead of the jQuery's `:last` selector. Of course if this is always run on page load, just use CSS rules instead.

Comment: Yes thanks. but its just an example, i have many jquery to optimize at each page.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.enter, .btnsecond').show();
jQuery('#id div.my-class, .classes p:last').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no programming logic applied in these javascript/jQuery statements, the fastest way to apply those initial conditions would be to just set them with CSS rules in a stylesheet, not with javascript.  This way they will be applied immediately before the page even displays, rather than set via javascript which has to wait until the DOM is loaded before it can run.

```css
.enter, .btnsecond {display: block;}
#id div.my-class, .classes p:last {display: none;}
```

Comment: ok. css is better cause its readed by the browser and have indenpendent process than javascript. will take care about that. but in case if Jquery is not Hide() or show() or css(). If its some initiate state depending of a variable ?

Comment: One thing to note is that IE8 or less does not support the :last CSS3 selector without a polyfill like http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @user784083 - I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment.  Are you asking a new question?

Comment: @Fostah - good point.  If the OP controls the HTML, they could apply a unique classname to the last paragraph and use that in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

To add to mgraphs code you can specify the context in your selector. Meaning you specify the containing element of your items so that it only searches that container for your elements. This reduces dom traversing.

```
$exampleContainerDiv = $("#ContainerDivForSelectorsBelowExample");
jQuery('.enter, .btnsecond', $exampleContainerDiv).show();
jQuery('#id div.my-class, .classes p:last', $exampleContainerDiv).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks. thats sound good. Is it a good practive using  context instead of find() ?

Comment: @user784083 You will have less DOM queries using a context. I normally only use find() to find specific elements within a selectors result.